# Input a text file and write multiple output files in Python

Tags: python

Hi folks I am inputting a filename.txt and producing multiple output files filename1.txt, filename2.txt and filename3.txt.  To be more specific here is the input data in filename.txt:

```
Time(ms)  Channel 1  Channel 2  Channel 3
0.0       4.5        3.6        125
1.0       3.0        3.4        98
2.0       100        3.0        59
3.0       23         45.9       2.1
4.0       34         123        35
5.0       2.1        222        98
```

filename1.txt should produce data of only columns Time and Channel 1
filename2.txt should produce data of only columns Time and Channel 2
filename3.txt should produce data of only columns Time and Channel 3

Source code:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as input:
    for i in range(1,4):
        with open('filename%i.txt' %i, 'w') as output:
            for line in input:
                columns = line.strip().split()
                for j in range(1,4):
                    output.write('{:10}{:10}\n'.format(columns[0], columns[j+1]))
```

Compiled I get text files filename1, filename2 and filename3 but only data in filename1.
What happened to filename2 and filename3 data?

Comment: You ought to go back and accept answers to some or all of your questions. See this answer on meta for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/166957

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for line in input` exhausts all the lines in the `input` file. You have to reload the file and start over again at the beginning if you want to go through them again... or copy them to another list first.

Comment: Thanks, just starting with Python.  Love it better than C.

Answer (score 4):

You only read the input once, but tried to iterate over all its lines thrice. You could either open all 3 outputs and write to all them simultaneously, or open the input 3 times (once for each output file). The best approach will depend on your specific requirements (the size of the file, the number of output files, etc).

Opening 3 times produces cleaner code, but it might be less efficient:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    with open('filename.txt', 'r') as input:
        with open('filename%i.txt' %i, 'w') as output:
            for line in input:
                columns = line.strip().split()
                output.write('{:10}{:10}\n'.format(columns[0], columns[i]))
```

A generalized solution for opening all output files at once would be better without the `with` clause:

```
files = [open('filename%i.txt' %i, 'w') for i in range(1,4)]
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        columns = line.strip().split()
        for j in range(1,4):
            files[j-1].write('{:10}{:10}\n'.format(columns[0], columns[j]))
for f in files:
    f.close()
```

(you'd have to handle exceptions manually too, in this case)

Comment: Thanks this helps. I just realized I am only reading once but writing thrice.  Is the "j" variable has some meaning?

Comment: nope. My mistake, when adapting your code I left the "j" there. Answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip. After 2nd `with` statement, add

```
input.seek(0)
```

could also do the trick.