# Python - Producing custom filename during creation

Tags: python

So I have a script that produces files named for each key in a dictionary. (script below)

```
 for key, values in sequencelist.items():
     with open(key, 'w') as out:
         for value in values:
             out.write('\n'.join(value.split()) + '\n')
```

Can someone help me modify the above syntax to do more? I would like to append some plain text onto the filename as well as add the current `len(dict.keys())` using `range()`  See my script below, which doesn't work! :)

```
for key, values in sequencelist.items():
    for i in range(len(sequencelist.keys())):
        j = i+1
        with open('OTU(%j)' +'_' + key +'.txt' %j, 'w') as out:
            for value in values:
                out.write('\n'.join(value.split()) + '\n')
```

So this the first file created would be OTU(1)_`key`.txt

I am sure the `with open()` line is 100% wrong.

Could someone also link me stuff to read on the use of `%j` to call the variable `j` from the line before works? I was trying to use code from this Overflow answer ([Input a text file and write multiple output files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542114/input-a-text-file-and-write-multiple-output-files-in-python)) with no explanation.

Comment: Your confusion about `%j` probably occurred because the code in the question you linked to happened to use `i` both as the format (integer) and as the name of the value to print. For this style of string formatting, see [these docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). There are [other ways](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to do formatting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
for count, (key, values) in enumerate(sequencelist.items()):
    with open('OTU(%d)_%s.txt' % (count+1, str(key)), 'w') as out:
        for value in values:
            out.write('\n'.join(value.split()) + '\n')
```

I swapped the ordering of your open call with your value iteration so you don't get `len(sequencelist)` files for each value. It seemed like your `j` argument was not required after this change. The enumerate call makes the count part of the for loop increment each time the loop repeats (it doesn't have to be called count).

The `%d` asks for an integer, the `%s` for a string, which depending on the key name will convert nicely with `str()`. If your key is some custom class you'll want to convert it to a nicer string format as you'll get someting like `<class __main__.Test at 0x00000....>`.

Comment: Perfect, I was going to ask for an explanation and mention you missed a " ' " someplace.

Comment: Opps, fixed the typo. Also you could shorten `range(len(sequencelist.keys())` to `range(len(sequencelist))` though it won't really change the runtime unless sequencelist is really long.

Comment: So I ran it, it works correctly except for one part. The script now makes 106 (the total len) copies of all 106 files. How can I tell it to only make that %d one time then move on to the next loop? Lol which generated 11,000 files haha

Comment: I see what you mean, that's kind of funny -- I didn't actually follow your code logic as much as your syntax. I'll update the answer to tell you how to swap the order.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't worked with python for months and even then I've only used it for a few months total. :) I am always learning new things.

Comment: No worries, I am doing the same thing with Ruby right now. Were you using that `j` for anything other than incremental file numbering?

Comment: No, I was just using it as a variable to hold the increasing len() digit. Your modified answer works perfectly. I'm a microbiologist by trade that is switching to CS on his own. Books can only teach you so much, where as SO can get you nice people such as yourself. Thank you for spending some time with me.